# Python trying to update a value in a 2D numpy array, value doesn't update

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sorry I'm a python noob.

I've been trying to find the max value in an 2D array representing x,y values.

The max value should then be replaced by 0 and plotted.   However i have tried many ways to replace the value and i cant get the value replaced.

My code so far is

```
m2= [ [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ] , [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ]]

a2 = np.array(m2, dtype=np.int)

plt.plot(a2[0,:], a2[1,:], 'r-x')

a2maxy = np.max(a2[1,:])
print("a2 y values: ", a2[1,:])

for y in (a2[1,:]):
    if (y==a2maxy):
        print(y)
        print("max found ", y)
        y=0
        print(y)
```

But my output (showing the max y value as unchanged is

```
a2 y values:  [0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3]
3
max found  3
0
3
max found  3
0
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not actually referencing the array of values you want to edit in the `for` loop. There's probably a slicker way to do this, but you can do what you want with [enumerate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) as the iterator in the `for` loop, and then referencing the item in the `a2` array you care about, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
m2= [ [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ] , [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ]]

a2 = np.array(m2, dtype=np.int)

plt.plot(a2[0,:], a2[1,:], 'r-x')

a2maxy = np.max(a2[1,:])
print("a2 y values: ", a2[1,:])

for idx,y in enumerate(a2[1,:]):
    if (y==a2maxy):
        print("max found ", y)
        a2[1,idx]=0

print("new a2 y values: ", a2[1,:])
```

and the output is now:

```
a2 y values:  [0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3]
max found  3
max found  3
new a2 y values:  [0 1 2 0 2 1 0 1 2 0]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to answer this, I see now where i was going wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The given answer by @lydiash is correct. But, as you're new to numpy, I'd like to also give you some insights about what's the point of using numpy :)

Let's simplify your code a bit. I see that `a2` contains all data for a plot. But first row, denoting `x` values, is needed only for plotting, and you're working only with actual `y` values. So, let's split them!

```py
xs = np.arange(10) # gives you exactly [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ]
ys = np.array([ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ])

plt.plot(xs, ys, 'r-x')
print(f'y values: {ys}') # prints "y values:  [0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3]"
```

In the second part you're looking for max `y` value and change it to zero. You can do it in a `for` loop, of course. But also you could make use of power of numpy - vector operations!

As you've calculated the max value with `y_max = np.max(ys)` (which also can be written as `y_max = ys.max()`), you can directly change `ys` in one hop:

```py
y_max = ys.max()
print(f'max value found: {y_max}')  # prints "max value found: 3"

ys[ys == y_max] = 0  # here the changing of max values to zero happens!
print(f'new y values: {ys}') # prints "new y values:  [0 1 2 0 2 1 0 1 2 0]"
```

Expression `ys == y_max` is kinda a filter on all indices of `ys` - only indices of matched values are taken.

---

*Optional clarification*: If you want to understand `ys == y_max` part better, just print what it gives:

```py
print(ys == y_max)
# prints "[False False False True False False False False False True]"
# as you see, `True` values are exactly at positions of maximum value
```

It gives you a mask on all indices of the array. And you can use it further as some sort of filter - `ys[mask]` returns only values filtered by that `mask`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking the time to explain this :), I had tried the np.where method and got nowhere

Comment: `np.where` is a bit tricky as it does two a bit different things depending on how many arguments you provide - I won't recommend using it before you got used to numpy. In general numpy has a tremendous docs for each function - don't be shy to look at them )